# How does a FAST tree look in practice?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, tree

I am looking at *[FAST: Fast Architecture Sensitive Tree Search on Modern CPUs and GPUs](http://kaldewey.com/pubs/FAST__SIGMOD10.pdf) by Kim et al.* and *[Index Search Algorithms for Databases and Modern CPUs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.06697.pdf) by Gross*, in order to find inspiration on how to further optimize B+trees to utilize SIMD lines, cache lines, and page sizes. In those documents they show these diagrams:

[image]
[image]

After reading the descriptions (*"5.1.1 Building the Tree"* in the first link, and pg 30-32 in the second link), I still don't have a visualization of what exactly they are doing to optimize the layout of the tree for these 3 features. What would the structure of the tree look like in pseudo-JavaScript or pseudo-C code or JSON? How does it differ from a regular B+tree? *(Obviously JS doesn't have these features available, but just wondering what the shape of the tree is generally, and where things go.)*